# How can i add an FontSwesome icon in the same line?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, devise, font-awesome

I use my rails with devise (login system). That works. Now I will add in FA-Icon to as my label.

This is my target:

[image]

But this my current state (the hook is my test icon):

[image]

That is my code:

```
    <div class="container">
  <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name), html: {class: "form-signin"}) do |f| %>
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
    
    <%#= f.label :email, 'Email Address', class: 'sr-only' %>
  
    <i class="fa-solid fa-check"></i>
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Email Address' %>
    

    <%= f.label :password, 'Password', class: 'sr-only' %>
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Password' %>

    <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label><%= f.check_box :remember_me %> Remember me</label>
        </div>
    <% end %>

    <%= f.button "Sign in", class: 'btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block' %>
  <% end %>
  <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
</div>
```

Can someone give me a hint, what i am doing wrong?

Comment: since you're using bootstrap, you can just use input groups, as they show here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/input-group/

Comment: I suggest you take a few minutes to scan the entire Bootstrap documentation so you're aware of what it provides.